# How extract vat number into page products?

Tags: customer, vat

I want to extract the vat number into product page.

For customer email or customer name I used:

```
$customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()
echo $customer->getEmail();
```

It is working work.

But for vat I used:

```
echo $customer->getTaxvat();
```

It is not working

Comment: google! $vatNumber = $customer->getData('taxvat');

Comment: I tried your approach and it is working on my side, are you sure the customer you are testing has a Vat number ? and are you using Community or Enterprise ?

Comment: community:
$customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
echo $customer->getEmail();  //work
echo "taxvat:". $vatNumber = $customer->getData('taxvat');
// not work!